# Ubuntu Gnome - after install no grub menu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have sucessfully installed Ubuntu Gnome next to Win 7 OS, but after install i get no grub menu. Windows 7 just starts itself ignoring Ubuntu completely. Is there a way i can boot from Ubuntu live cd and manualy create grub menu?

Please post your sugestions below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your ubuntu from a live cd called SuperGrubDisk2, which automatically detects any system on the pc. When successfully booted, you have to reinstall the GRUB-Bootloader:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

(where 'x' is the appropriate character for your harddisk, probably 'a')